# Select tables that contain a specific value (Postgres)

Tags: database, postgresql

in my DB there are more than 100 tables. Some of them have a column name "date".
I want to get all tables (table names) for a specific date.

so far I have been able to retrieve the table names that contain a date attribute:

```
SELECT pg_class.relname
FROM pg_class

INNER JOIN pg_attribute 
ON pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid

WHERE pg_attribute.attname = 'date'
```

but I want to do somethin like that and it doesn´t work of course:

```
SELECT pg_class.relname
FROM pg_class

INNER JOIN pg_attribute 
ON pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid

WHERE pg_attribute.attname = 'date'
AND date = '2014-12-05'
```

Comment: You will need to write some code for this (unless your SQL client supports something like that)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that loops through the tables you've found and execute dynamically composed queries in it.
([Executing dynamic queries in PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN))